# ''adonis' is not recognized as an internal or external command' problem even though I installed the CLI globally

Tags: node.js, npm, adonis.js

My Windows 10 PC forces me to install CLI and assign environment varriables (happens when I install ionic). This time, same trouble with Adonis. First, the problem is `'adonis' is not recognized as an internal or external command'`

To solve this, I have installed Adonis locally in `C:\Users\mq003\AppData\Local\node_modules`. Which I receive is the only `@Adonis` directory and it doesn't come with a `.cmd` file so I can't use this. Therefore, I imported directly the cli from github with  `npm i -save @adonisjs/cli` and copy the `.cmd` files in `npm` directory, while others will be put in `node_modules` (because my Path declare I put the cmd there).

[image: npm directory]

As you can see, all `ngrok`, `ionic`, etc. commands belong here. They all work perfectly fine in every terminals.

When I try to type adonis commands, this time, it said.

```
PS D:\adonis project> adonis --help
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\mq003\AppData\Roaming\@adonisjs\cli\index.js'
?[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:623:15)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:527:27)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10)?[39m
?[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11?[39m {
  code: ?[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'?[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

I think it requires `@adonisjs` directory outside, not in `node_modules`. So I get that directory out (as you can see in the picture). However, the error still exists.

[image: roaming directory]

Editted: I found an issue posted on Github seems relevant to my problem. I will link here in case it helps.

[Github](https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-cli/issues/151)

Comment: Your `adonisjs` dir resides in `...\AppData\Roaming\npm`, while the expected path is  `...\AppData\Roaming`.

Comment: You are right, thanks. However, it still doesn't work and have the same problem. I have updated the picture for my roaming directory.

Comment: I found the solution to this. Instead of using the @adonisjs directory from npm i @adonisjs/cli --save, I clone their github directly instead and put it into @adonisjs/cli. It works this time.